# No ethernet link detected on internal ethernet connection

Tags: linux, ethernet

We have a device with two controllers internally connected via ethernet. Both devices run Linux. One of the controller is the main controller which powers the other internal controller on after startup.

Sporadically it happens that the ethernet interfaces on both devices do not detect a link.

Rebooting the internal controller does not solve the issue. Only rebooting the complete devices solves the problem.

This happens on several devices. Therefore we think this is not caused by a defect cable or something like this.

Any ideas why this happens sometimes and how to solve this or further investigate?

More Details:

Main controller
Kernel version: 5.15.41-ga9c39740b72d-ab20230528
Ethernet transceiver: DP83867CRRGZR

Internal controller
Kernel version: 5.4.47-gdf79e6b2d
Ethernet transceiver: DP83867CRRGZR

"ip address show dev eth0" shows the following on both controllers:
`eth0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN group default qlen 1000`

Comment: "We have a device" - this post is much too vague and general.

Comment: Yes, I know, but I am not sure, which information you need. Just let me know, what you need and I will provide the details.

Comment: Without knowing anything, how can we ask for details?

Comment: Added some more details but I don't know if that helps. If not, please let me know which details you need.

Comment: Honestly, this sounds more like a task for Electronics.SE...

Comment: Which Linux distribution and version? "do not detect a link" - meaning no internet?

Comment: The internal controller has Debian 10 and the main controller has Android 12 (ok, not really Linux). No link detected means that "ethtool eth0" shows "Link detected: no" and no TCP connection can be established between the two controllers. Attempting to ping the main controller from the internal controller results in "Destination Host Unreachable" error.